# How do I create an index variable for unique values of X within a group Y?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, case-when

I have the following table:

```
id_question  id_event   num_events
2015012713    49508          1
2015012711    49708          1
2015011523    41808          3
2015011523    44008          3
2015011523    44108          3
2015011522    41508          3
2015011522    43608          3
2015011522    43708          3
2015011521    39708          1
2015011519    44208          1
```

The third column gives the count of events by question. I want to create a variable that would index the events by question only where there are multiple events per question. It would look something like that:

```
id_question  id_event   num_events  index_event
2015012713    49508          1          
2015012711    49708          1          
2015011523    41808          3          1
2015011523    44008          3          2
2015011523    44108          3          3
2015011522    41508          3          1
2015011522    43608          3          2
2015011522    43708          3          3
2015011521    39708          1          
2015011519    44208          1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to create an 'index_event' after grouping by 'id_question'.  If the number of rows are greater than 1 (`n() >1`), then get the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) and the default option in `case_when` is `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id_question) %>%
   mutate(index_event = case_when(n() >1 ~ row_number()))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id_question [6]
#   id_question id_event num_events index_event
#         <int>    <int>      <int>       <int>
# 1  2015012713    49508          1          NA
# 2  2015012711    49708          1          NA
# 3  2015011523    41808          3           1
# 4  2015011523    44008          3           2
# 5  2015011523    44108          3           3
# 6  2015011522    41508          3           1
# 7  2015011522    43608          3           2
# 8  2015011522    43708          3           3
# 9  2015011521    39708          1          NA
#10  2015011519    44208          1          NA
```

---

Or with `data.table`, we use `rowid` on 'id_question' and change the elements that are 1 in 'num_events' to `NA` with `NA^` (making use of `NA^0`, `NA^1`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, index_event := rowid(id_question) * NA^(num_events == 1)]
```

---

Or using `base R`, another option with the `sequence` of frequency from 'id_question' and change elements to NA as in the previous case

```
df1$index_event <-  with(df1, sequence(table(id_question)) * NA^(num_events == 1))
df1$index_event
#[1] NA NA  1  2  3  1  2  3 NA NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id_question = c(2015012713L, 2015012711L, 2015011523L, 
2015011523L, 2015011523L, 2015011522L, 2015011522L, 2015011522L, 
2015011521L, 2015011519L), id_event = c(49508L, 49708L, 41808L, 
44008L, 44108L, 41508L, 43608L, 43708L, 39708L, 44208L), num_events = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `num_events = 1` you can return `NA` or create a row-index for each `id_question`.

This can be done in base R :

```
df$index_event <- with(df, ave(num_events == 1, id_question, 
                       FUN = function(x) replace(seq_along(x), x, NA))) 

df
#   id_question id_event num_events index_event
#1   2015012713    49508          1          NA
#2   2015012711    49708          1          NA
#3   2015011523    41808          3           1
#4   2015011523    44008          3           2
#5   2015011523    44108          3           3
#6   2015011522    41508          3           1
#7   2015011522    43608          3           2
#8   2015011522    43708          3           3
#9   2015011521    39708          1          NA
#10  2015011519    44208          1          NA
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id_question) %>% 
   mutate(index_event = if_else(num_events == 1, NA_integer_, row_number()))
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,index_event := ifelse(num_events == 1, NA_integer_, seq_len(.N)), id_question]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id_question = c(2015012713L, 2015012711L, 2015011523L, 
2015011523L, 2015011523L, 2015011522L, 2015011522L, 2015011522L, 
2015011521L, 2015011519L), id_event = c(49508L, 49708L, 41808L, 
44008L, 44108L, 41508L, 43608L, 43708L, 39708L, 44208L), num_events = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L)),class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```